# Создание процедуры для подсчёта количества записей в PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

```
CREATE PROCEDURE products_count(INOUT cnt BIGINT)
    LANGUAGE SQL
    AS $$
    SELECT count(*) into cnt FROM products;
    $$;
```

Но тут пошло что-то не так:

```
ОШИБКА:  несовпадение типа возврата в функции (в объявлении указан тип record)
DETAIL:  Последним оператором в функции должен быть SELECT или INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE RETURNING.
CONTEXT:  SQL-функция "products_count"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это language sql. `SELECT ... INTO` не имеет никакого отношения к параметрам функции или процедуры - это синтаксис создания таблицы.

Результатом выполнения запроса

```
SELECT count(*) into cnt FROM products;
```

Станет таблица с именем `cnt` и одной колонкой `count` типа `bigint`.

Чтобы сформировать в `language sql` выходные параметры - необходимо сделать просто `select` либо insert/update/delete с указанием returning. Никак указывать что это должен быть результат вызова процедуры или функции не нужно, достаточно самого факта что это запрос и он хочет вернуть какие-то данные:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE products_count(INOUT cnt BIGINT)
    LANGUAGE SQL
    AS $$
    SELECT count(*) FROM am;
    $$;

CALL products_count(null);
```